# Rails Hidden field tag - Remove "value" key from parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hidden-field

I have this code in my view:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :comment_id, '1'%>
```

It essentially creates this for `params`

`params = {"commit"=>"No Phrase to Add", "comment_id"=>"{:value=>1}"}`

I want to extract the `comment_id` of `1` from the above hash. `params[:comment_id][:value]` throws an error, because I'm not looking at the key directly but a hash as a string instead.

How can I remove the `value` key or access the `comment_id` of `1` above?

goal : `"comment_id" => 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
eval(params["comment_id"])[:value]
=> 1
```

The eval would convert the string value of `params["comment_id"]` into an actual hash, and then you can easily retrieve the value from it.

Comment: Using eval in this case is very dangerous.